# Remove quotes from yaml file property with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I'm mapping a yaml file with Jackson and then I add one property to finally write in a File the updated yaml.

The property is mapped with @JsonAnySetter because it is unknow the number of tenants in the yaml and they are not listed as array.

```
@JsonAnySetter
private Map<String, Tenant> tenants = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper(
                  new YAMLFactory().disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER)
                  .enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES));

        File yaml = new File("/Users/user/Desktop/application.yml");

        ApplicationTenants appTenant = mapper.readValue(yaml, ApplicationTenants.class);

        String tenantName = "newTenant";

        Tenant newTenant = new Tenant();
        newTenant.setAvailable(true);
        newTenant.setAccountId("accountId");        newTenant.setAuthority("authority");

        appTenant.getRccloud().getTenants().put(tenantName, newTenant);

        File updatedFile = new File("/Users/user/Desktop/application2.yml");

        mapper.writeValue(updatedFile, appTenant);

    }
```

After this, the updated file shows some tenant names with double quote, like this:

```
tenants:
  tenant1: ...
  "tenant2": ...
  "tenant3": ...
  tenant4: ...
  newtenant: ...
```

The input yaml contains all the tenants without quotes and I want to keep it like that.

Any suggestion on how can I remove the duble quotes on the tenant name?

Comment: Unfortunately YAML has some non-obvious ambiguities, for example `no` without quotes is a boolean `false` value. Maybe it's one of these cases. Also different YAML parsers even interpret these cases differently. It is actually safer to use quotes in all cases of strings. See for example: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3669238/7-yaml-gotchas-to-avoidand-how-to-avoid-them.html